# So, in connected speech, we can only connect A with B if A is "a strong or weak word" & B is "a weak word", right?

Tags: speech

I discovered this rule in connected speech.

I asked this question many times but seem no one has a proper answer.

See this saying at **11:45** in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=828-I8GsV1o&feature=youtu.be&t=11m45s) "*My room is on the fifth floor. I had to walk up with my luggage.*"

There is a linking between "***is-on***" `/ɪzɔːn/` since "**is**" & "**on**" are both weak.

However, there is no connection between "**walk**" & "**up**" since "**up**" is emphasized.

However, see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYx_pTuLvmE&feature=youtu.be&t=3m17s) at **3:17**, the lady said "*I'll call Oliver*".

There is a connection between "**call**" & "**Oliver**" `/kɔː'lɒl.ɪvɚ/`, so I predict that "**Oliver**" is not emphasized or is weak!

So, from these above research, I can conclude that:

There will be a connection between **A** & **B** (**A** stands before **B**), for Example "**Wake up**" (**A**: wake & **B**: up), if:

- **A**: strong word & **B**: weak word
- **A**: weak word & **B**: weak word

There will be **NO** connection between **A** & **B**, if:

- **A**: strong word & **B**: strong word
- **A**: weak word & **B**: strong word

I asked this question many times but seem no native English speaker could provide a proper answer.

**I will thank you so much if any of you can provide a proper answer for it!**

**Note**: I think a strong word in a sentence is the word that we want to emphasize & we really want the listener to hear that word. The strong word is the word that is very important in a sentence. On the contrary, weak word is the word that is not very important in a sentence & we don't want to emphasize it.

Comment: Please define "weak" and "strong" English words in an operational way.

Comment: The word *"Oliver"* in *"I'll call Oliver"* really should be stressed (and it is in the video), which I think should make it a *"strong word"*. So your rule doesn't always work.

Comment: @deadrat, I updated my question

Comment: @PeterShor, I think the speaker can decide which word in a sentence is strong ans which one is weak. SO the lady said "*I'll call Oliver*" does not want to emphasize "*Oliver*". You can hear in the video that the word "Oliver" has a rather low pitch.

Comment: I don't hear that. It sounds to me like she's emphasizing *"Oliver"*. What word do you think she's emphasizing.

Comment: The choice to emphasize a word has much more to do with the meaning you wish to convey than the word that comes before it.  If it were completely unsurprising that Oliver be called then *Oliver* might not be emphasized, but if *Tom* was the expected party to be called, then the speaker could emphasize that "contrary to expectations, I'm going to call Oliver" by  emphasizing *Oliver*. Likewise if it was expected that someone else was going to call Oliver, you might say, "***I'm** going to call Oliver*".  Any word in that sentence can be emphasized- with different nuance in meaning.

Comment: I think that if we ***really*** want to emphasize a word very strongly, in some dialects we don't link the previous word to it. But if you use this as the definition of "strong" word, I believe that for many English speakers, there will be lots of sentences where there are only weak words.

Comment: You've failed to define "weak", "strong", and "connection", so it's impossible to tell what you're trying to say.

Comment: Note that one might, when seeking someone to fix your computer, suddenly get a bright idea and blurt out excitedly "I'll call Oliver!!".  Or, after struggling to fix the computer for hours, and listening to your wife nag you to get assistance, you might, in a monotone, say "OK, I'll call Oliver."  Entirely different emphasis for the same words.

Answer (score 1):

The relationships between language structure and stress have preoccupied many linguists, and they are often discussed in this forum.  One parallel that is often drawn is to rhythm in music, and there seems to be some similarity between your observations about connecting weak and strong words and the common 4/4 rhythm in simple tunes, where the notes of a measure are accented 1-4-2-4, Oom-pah-oom-pah, reflecting a structure ((1-4)(2-4)).

I did a Google web search on the pattern "language rhythm music" and saw many interesting references.  An ambitious attempt to approach musical structure in a way that parallels the structural analysis of language and might interest you is the 1983 [Generative Theory of Tonal Music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_theory_of_tonal_music).